# $N\unlhd G$ such that $|N|<\infty$ then we have $M\unlhd G$ with $|G/M|<\infty$ and $mn=nm ~\forall m\in M,n\in N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Now, the question is :

Assuming $N\unlhd G$ such that $|N|<\infty$ Question is to prove that :

we have $M\unlhd G$ with $|G/M|<\infty$ and $mn=nm ~\forall m\in M,n\in N$

As i am assuming $G$ is infinite group, I just can not take $Z(G)$ to be $M$ as of course $Z(G)\unlhd G$ and $mn=nm$ for all $n\in N,m\in Z(G)$ but $|G/Z(G)|$ may not be finite.

I had some thoughts but they all getting messed up.

please provide some hints for me to attack this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Consider the kernel of the action of $G$ on $N$

Comment: $G$ acts on $N$ by conjugation... $|N|=n$...this gives $\eta: G\rightarrow S_n$ then we have $G/Ker(\eta)\cong H\leq S_n$.. So, we have $Ker(\eta)\unlhd G, |G/ker(\eta)|\leq n$... that is alright.. i have to now look for commutative property.... :O

Comment: As said by user8268, $G$ acts on $N$ by conjugation, thus $G/C_G(N)$  can be embeded in $Aut(N)$ which is finite as $N$ is finite.  And by definition $C_G(N)$ commutes with $N$.

Comment: Oh, I was just writing $Ker(\eta)$ for the required normal group but did not notice that $Ker(\eta)=C_G(N)$ Thank you anywasys :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Do you know the correctness of the claim as it is in the title when the group $G$ is finite?

Comment: @B.S. : I would just take $Z(G)$ when $G$ is finite... i have already said that in the question.. I think i did not got your question could you please explain what you want to hear from me...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I just wanted to say that if $G$ is finite then the claim (as it is in the title) is wrong and we can find a good counterexample for it. But if $G$ is infinite, I am not sure what the argument would be. I have thought about this case but nothing happens in my mind. :(